# laravel php add to associated array generates new nodes

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

This is my array:

This is my final array:

```
$data = [
            'domain'=> $xmlDocument->domain,
            'FirstDate' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->first_date,
            'LastDate' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->last_date,
            'Category' => $xmlDocument->category->name,
            'Action' => $xmlDocument->websiteAction->name,
            'Source' => $xmlDocument->source->name,
            'LogFile' => $xmlDocument->log_file,
            'DateAttribute' => [
                        'Name' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->name,
                        'Place' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->dateLocation->name,
                        'DateFunction' => $xmlDocument->dateAttribute->dateFunction->name
                    ],
            'MasterPage' => [
                'MasterAttributes' =>[

                ],
                'Container'=>[
                    'xpath' => $xmlDocument->masterInformation->xpath
                ],
                'NextPage' =>[],
                'LinkAttribute'=>[]
            ],
        ];
```

as you see, the `MasterAttributes` key is an empty array and I want to fille it.

#### What I have tried

```
$attributes = $xmlDocument->masterInformation->masterAttributes;
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    $masterAttribute = [
        'Attribute' => [
            'name' => $attribute->attributeName->name,
            'default_value' => $attribute->default_value
        ]
    ];
    $data['MasterPage'] ['MasterAttributes'][] = $masterAttribute;
}
```

The generated xml is:

```
<MasterAttributes>
         <item0>
            <Attribute>
               <name>bathroom</name>
               <default_value>This is the default value</default_value>
            </Attribute>
         </item0>
         <item1>
            <Attribute>
               <name>price</name>
               <default_value>vfd</default_value>
            </Attribute>
         </item1>
         <item2>
            <Attribute>
               <name>bathroom</name>
               <default_value>new default value</default_value>
            </Attribute>
         </item2>
      </MasterAttributes>
```

please check that there are extract `item0, item1, item2`

how to remove them please?

## Update 1

after the first answer from `@lowerends`, I got this result

```
 <MasterAttributes>
         <Attribute_0>
            <name>bathroom</name>
            <default_value>This is the default value</default_value>
         </Attribute_0>
         <Attribute_1>
            <name>price</name>
            <default_value>vfd</default_value>
         </Attribute_1>
         <Attribute_2>
            <name>bathroom</name>
            <default_value>new default value</default_value>
         </Attribute_2>
      </MasterAttributes>
```

very close to waht I need but I need to have `Attribute` not `Attribute 0` or `Attribute 1`

#### Update 2

I generated the xml like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><websiteInformation></websiteInformation>");
        $this->array_to_xml($data,$xml);
        $xml->asXML("FileName".XmlDocument::find($id)->id.".xml");
```

where `$data` is the finall array, and `array_to_xml` function is:

```
 public  function array_to_xml($student_info, &$xml_student_info) {
        foreach($student_info as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(!is_numeric($key)){
                    $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("$key");
                    $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                }
                else{
                    $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("item$key");
                    $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                }
            }
            else {
                $xml_student_info->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where comes from the `$xmlDocument` variable?

Comment: @martinezjc didn't get you sorry. what did you mean

Comment: `$xmlDocument` is an object but i don't see the content of this variable in your question :P

Comment: @martinezjc the question is about arrays, not about the content of that variable though the array gives some data inside it.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent, You can't use duplicate nodes.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha isn't there any work arround to that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$attributes = $xmlDocument->masterInformation->masterAttributes;
foreach($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
    $masterAttribute = [
        'name' => $attribute->attributeName->name,
        'default_value' => $attribute->default_value
    ];
    $data['MasterPage']['MasterAttributes']["Attribute_$key"] = $masterAttribute;
}
```

This will make sure that you don't have duplicate `<Attribute>` elements in your `<MasterAttributes>` element.

Comment: +1, your answer is so close to what I need, but still the result is `Attribute 0` and `Attribue 1`. However I need just `Attribute`

Comment: I just removed `_$key` from your code and I got what I need. 1000000000000000 thanks

Comment: no sorry I didn't work, when I removed the `_key`, I end up with one `Attribue` node, though I need all of them not just one . please help

Comment: Indeed, that's why I had put that last sentence in my answer. You can't have duplicate array keys. How are you generating the `XML` from this array?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key in the index name

```
$data['MasterPage']['MasterAttributes']["Attribute"][] = $masterAttribute;
```

Hope this works :)